# How to delete all files in current directory but keep files in subfolders

Tags: filesystem, directory, delete

I have a structure like this

- file_1
- file_2
  ...
- file_n
- folder1/

  - sub_file_1
  - sub_file_2

I only want to delete file_1, file_2 and file_n but keep all folders and files in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run:

```
rm *
```

It's that simple.  It won't touch the directories unless you add the -R or -r flag:

```
rm -r *
```

If you also want to delete empty directories, add the --dir flag:

```
rm --dir *
```

Answer (score 2):

`rm` without the `-r`, disabling recursive directory removal flag and shell globbing:

```
rm /path/to/dir/*
```

Add the `-f` if you don't want to be prompted.

You can also use `find`:

```
find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

which works because of a `maxdepth` of 1, thus selecting only top-level files.